# Получить Category_ID из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Я хочу получить Category_ID из таблицы tbl_menu. В таблице tbl_menu есть Category_ID , но при добавлении Category_ID в SELECT получаю пустую страницу.

**Вот сам запрос**

```
    if(empty($keyword)){
        $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Category_name, Price, Serve_for, Menu_image, Quantity  
                FROM tbl_menu m, tbl_category c
                WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID  
                ORDER BY m.Menu_ID DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
    }else{
        $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Category_name, Price, Serve_for, Menu_image, Quantity  
                FROM tbl_menu m, tbl_category c
                WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID AND Menu_name LIKE ? 
                ORDER BY m.Menu_ID DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
    }

    $stmt_paging = $connect->stmt_init();
    if($stmt_paging ->prepare($sql_query)) {
        // Bind your variables to replace the ?s
        if(empty($keyword)){
            $stmt_paging ->bind_param('ss', $from, $offset);
        }else{
            $stmt_paging ->bind_param('sss', $bind_keyword, $from, $offset);
        }
        // Execute query
        $stmt_paging ->execute();
        // store result 
        $stmt_paging ->store_result();

        $stmt_paging->bind_result($data['Menu_ID'], 
                $data['Menu_name'], 
                $data['Category_name'],
                $data['Price'], 
                $data['Serve_for'],
                $data['Menu_image'],
                $data['Quantity']
                );
```

Comment: На пустоту Вы тестите `$keyword`, а в запрос передаёте `$bind_keyword`. Это какая-то могучая магия? Ну и вообще все операторы надо проверять на предмет "а не было ли ошибки"... И да - а почему заведомо числовым `$from` и `$offset` указан в привязке строковый тип?

Comment: ну и в догонку -> Что это за сокращение такое `tbl_menu m` ?  Почему не `tbl_menu as m` ?

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev в mysql допускается писать псевдонимы названий без ключевого слова as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пустая страница - это 500 ошибка? Хорошо бы ошибку явно получить.

Поскольку Category_ID есть в обоих таблицах, в Select надо добавить m.Category_ID  - иначе сервер не понимает. поле из какой таблицы ему выводить.